# How to retrieve result of calling a script from within a Python function?

Tags: python, function

I would like to call an external script from within a function, for instance:

```
import subprocess

def call_script(script):
   subprocess.call(script)
   return answer #retrieving the result is the part I'm struggling with

call_script("/user/bin/calc_delta.py")
```

The script calc_delta.py simply prints the result when it is done. How can I assign the result of that script to a variable? Thank you.

Comment: You should use `/` instead of `\\`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `subprocess.call` you should use `Popen` and call `communicate` on it.

That will allow you to read `stdout` and `stderr`. You can also input data with `stdin`.

Example from the docs http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote:

```
output = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at subprocess.Popen ([popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3))

For instance (from the docs):

```
pipe = Popen("cmd", shell=True, bufsize=bufsize, stdout=PIPE).stdout
```

`subprocess.call` is only going to give you the response code for your call, not the output.

Answer (score 2):

In Python ≥2.7 / ≥3.1, you could use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to convert the stdout into a str.

```
answer = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/calc_delta.py'])
```

There are also `subprocess.getstatusoutput` and `subprocess.getoutput` on Python ≥3.1 if what you need is a shell command, but it is supported on *NIX only.